# Loan calculator math incorrect

Tags: java, loops, math, methods, calculator

I have been working on this program for about a week now and I can't seem to get my math right. 
It's outputting values, just not the correct ones. I have looked over my values too many times 
to count. I'm desperate!! My program calculates yearly interests over however many years the length
of the loan is. Secondly it calculates how much is left to pay on the original loan yearly over the 
total length of the loan.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class mortgageCalc {


     public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        // Other declarations for main program go here
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double annualInterest;
        int loanLength;
        double loanAmount;


        // Step 1: prompt for, read in, and store the input values.
        System.out.print("Enter loan amount: ");
        loanAmount = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter length of the loan: ");
        loanLength = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter interest rate as percent: ");
        annualInterest = keyboard.nextDouble();

        double newMonthlyPayment = payment(annualInterest,loanLength,loanAmount);
        double totalInterest = (newMonthlyPayment * loanLength*12)-loanAmount;
        printTotals(newMonthlyPayment, totalInterest,annualInterest,loanLength,loanAmount);
        double balance = loanAmount;
        double monthlyInterestRate = annualInterest/1200;

        for (int year = 1; year <= loanLength; year++)
        {
          double remainingMonthlyInterest = getMonthlyInterest (balance, monthlyInterestRate);
          double remainingInterest = totalInterest + remainingMonthlyInterest;
          balance = getRemainingBalance(balance, newMonthlyPayment, remainingMonthlyInterest);
          System.out.println("Monthly interest:"+remainingMonthlyInterest);
          System.out.println("new balance:"+balance);
        }
      } // end of main

      public static double payment(double annualInterest, int loanLength, double loanAmount)
      {
        double i = (annualInterest/1200);
        double n = (loanLength*12);
        double e1 = i+1;
        double e2 = Math.pow(e1,n);
        double e3 = e2-1;
        double e4 = i * e2;
        double e5 = e2-1;
        double monthlyPayment = loanAmount*(e4/e5);
        return monthlyPayment;
      } // end of function payment
      public static void printTotals(double newMonthlyPayment, double totalInterest,double
      annualInterest,int loanLength, double loanAmount)
      { 
           System.out.print("For a "+loanLength);
           System.out.printf(" year loan of $%5.2f ",loanAmount);
           System.out.printf("at %5.2f ",annualInterest);
           System.out.println("interest--");

           System.out.printf("Monthly payment: $ %5.2f\n",newMonthlyPayment);
           System.out.printf("Total interest:  $ %6.2f\n",totalInterest);
       } // end of function printTotals
      public static double getMonthlyInterest (double balance, double monthlyInterestRate)
      {
          double monthlyInterest=0.0;
          for(int month=1; month<=12; month++)
          {
           monthlyInterest = balance * monthlyInterestRate;
          }
          return monthlyInterest;
      }
      public static double getRemainingBalance (double balance, double newMonthlyPayment,
      double monthlyInterest)
      {
         double newBalance=0.0;
         for(int month=1; month<=12; month++)
        {
          newBalance = balance-(newMonthlyPayment-monthlyInterest);
        }
       return newBalance;
      }
} // end of class MortgageCalc
```

Comment: Please state a question. Tell us your inputs, your expected outputs, and your actual outputs.

Comment: Can you post an example input and then what your expected and actual output is?

Comment: Sure. my input example  90,000 (original loan) 15 (length of loan) 6.75(interest rate(set))

Comment: Your payment computation appears incorrect (`e3` is assigned, but never used). Multiplying `i` by `e2`, which is based on `i`, is also highly suspicious. Please check your formulas.

Comment: year/interest/loan balance: year 1: interest loan:5965.23 loan balance :86408.21 and this must go through all 15 years

Comment: Why do you declare all those variables in `payment`? It's not necesary! With an efective interest rate `r` and a number of periods `n` you have all you need: `return (1 - Math.pow(1+r, -n)) / r;`!

Comment: Too much unneeded variables are too much places things can go wrong

Comment: @Jengo And **don't post question details as comments**. Edit your question and include the relevant information

Comment: I added on to a previous program. The question I'm asking about only deals with the last two methods.

Comment: `newBalance` is assigned to in a loop; maybe should use `+=`. I am really checking the interest calculation, but saw that `e3` is not used. Also there are no corrections, as double values are imprecise, so you might get deviations of cents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getMonthlyInterest()` method does not appear to be correct. While I don't know for sure what the math is supposed to be, what you have currently will iterate 12 times (once per month) and each time completely reset `monthlyInterest` to be `balance*monthlyInterestRate`

You should either not have a for loop, or probably more accurately should add the monthlyInterest to itself every month:

```
monthlyInterest = monthlyInterest + balance*monthlyInterestRate;
```

Same thing with your `getRemainingBalance()` method. It is being reset every iteration of the monthly for loop. Either get rid of the for loop or make sure your logic is correct--where `newBalance` uses information that changes from month to month during the loop.

Comment: I think you forgot += in your code snippet

Comment: @Joeblade No I did not. I have monthlyInterest being added to itself. I did not want to introduce the += notation just for fear of confusing Jengo, who I assume is a new programmer.

Comment: hehe fair enough :D to me it's less readable this way but I see why you are doing it.

Comment: Thanks guys for all the information! Ill get back to working on it